# Eclipse fails to detect classes generated by protoc using maven-protoc-plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to create a simple maven project which compiles a `.proto` file and produces a `.jar` which can be used by other projects. My `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.iar</groupId>
    <artifactId>cspyserver-cdp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>google-protoc</id>
            <url>http://sergei-ivanov.github.com/maven-protoc-plugin/repo/releases</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.protobuf.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-protoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.3.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Another maven project tries to refer to the classes generated by this module, using

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.iar</groupId>
        <artifactId>cspyserver-cdp</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This works find when I build on the command line, I can run my generated jar fine. But when I try to use this in Eclipse, the Eclipse java compiler says that it cannot resolve any of the modules generated by the protoc compiler.

I can get around this by building the maven module containing the protobuf stuff "offline" (using `mvn install`), and not having the project in the Eclipse workspace, but when I have both of the projects in the workspace, the protobuf classes are not found.

Something is wrong with how Eclipse detects dependencies in multi module projects, but I cannot figure out what.

Comment: Are you using m2e, i.e. standard plugin? Usually generators generate an additional src folder under target/generated-sources, which is not being included?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. Yes, I have m2e installed, and the project was created from inside Eclipse (File -> New -> Other -> Maven -> Maven Project). I don't know what other alternatives there are. How can I see if there is a source folder which isn't being included, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if you can get m2e to map the proto execution to a lifecycle..

i.e. something similar to:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
      <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          <pluginExecutions>
            <pluginExecution>
              <pluginExecutionFilter>
                <groupId>com.google.protobuf.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-protoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <versionRange>[0.3.2,)</versionRange>
                <goals>
                  <goal>compile</goal>
                  <goal>testCompile</goal>
                </goals>
              </pluginExecutionFilter>
              <action>
                <ignore></ignore>
              </action>
            </pluginExecution>
          </pluginExecutions>
        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```